UnprocessableEntityException when assigning a DTO as datatype for request body
I'm creating a POST gateway like this:
@Controller('users')
@ApiTags('user')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

  @Post('register')
  @ApiBody({ type: NewUserInputDto })
  registerUser(@Body() newUserInput: NewUserInputDto) {
    return this.userService.registerUser(newUserInput);
  }
}

The 'NewUserInputDto' looks like this:
export class NewUserInputDto {

    @ApiProperty()
    fullName: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    phone: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    email: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    password: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    retypedPassword: string;
}

When I try to send a request with the body matching the DTO, it just return this error (I did customize some of the exception message so that they are clearer):
[Nest] 47901  - 09/23/2024, 10:49:05 AM   ERROR [HttpExceptionFilter] Object:
[
  {
    "target": {
      "fullName": "string",
      "phone": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "password": "string",
      "retypedPassword": "string"
    },
    "value": "string",
    "property": "fullName",
    "constraints": {
      "whitelistValidation": "property fullName should not exist"
    }
  },
  {
    "target": {
      "fullName": "string",
      "phone": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "password": "string",
      "retypedPassword": "string"
    },
    "value": "string",
    "property": "phone",
    "constraints": {
      "whitelistValidation": "property phone should not exist"
    }
  },
  {
    "target": {
      "fullName": "string",
      "phone": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "password": "string",
      "retypedPassword": "string"
    },
    "value": "string",
    "property": "email",
    "constraints": {
      "whitelistValidation": "property email should not exist"
    }
  },
  {
    "target": {
      "fullName": "string",
      "phone": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "password": "string",
      "retypedPassword": "string"
    },
    "value": "string",
    "property": "password",
    "constraints": {
      "whitelistValidation": "property password should not exist"
    }
  },
  {
    "target": {
      "fullName": "string",
      "phone": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "password": "string",
      "retypedPassword": "string"
    },
    "value": "string",
    "property": "retypedPassword",
    "constraints": {
      "whitelistValidation": "property retypedPassword should not exist"
    }
  }
]

[Nest] 47901  - 09/23/2024, 10:49:05 AM   ERROR [HttpExceptionFilter] property fullName should not exist
UnprocessableEntityException: Unprocessable Entity Exception
    at ValidationPipe.exceptionFactory (/home/long/vegeta/HealthyFoodApplication_BackEnd/src/main.ts:74:16)
    at ValidationPipe.transform (/home/long/vegeta/HealthyFoodApplication_BackEnd/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js:72:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at resolveParamValue (/home/long/vegeta/HealthyFoodApplication_BackEnd/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:147:23)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at pipesFn (/home/long/vegeta/HealthyFoodApplication_BackEnd/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:150:13)
    at /home/long/vegeta/HealthyFoodApplication_BackEnd/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:37:30
POST /api/v1/users/register 422 115 - 10.342 ms

What might be the problem here?
I tried removing the data type constraint (which looks like this registerUser(@Body() newUserInput)) and it works just fine.
I also write other gateway in the similar way and they work just fine


First of all, when the root of the problem is unclear, you could try to restrain the problem to smaller parts in order to detect it. In the current one, I would keep it to controller Layer and i.e. comment out the call to the userService or better use the Debugger of your tool to identify the point where the program crashes.

The error mentions "fullName property should not exist", which is again weird, as you declare it in your DTO. Again, here you could try with fewer properties in the DTO and then check/watch what happens

In your DTO class, you do not use at all any Validators, which is the whole point of a DTO class and it's usefuleness. One benefit from that, is to have this class stop you and return a proper message why i.e. some input is not correct according to your program logic. For example, the fullName should be a string.

In your DTO you do not use '!' or '?' to your properties, to match it with TS potential and exploit it.


Below, I place a sample DTO, little more extended than yours, which can give you an idea how to structure it. What Validators you can use, place description in ApiProperty, possibly include default values or define an explicit constructor of the class. I tried the same Controller and DTO and it works fine, as you do not provide any further info of what happens in your Service Layer or your DB.
import { ApiProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger";
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty, IsPhoneNumber, IsString, IsStrongPassword, MinLength, ValidateIf } from "class-validator";

export class NewUserInputDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(2)
  fullName!: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsPhoneNumber()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  phone!: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsEmail()
  email!: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsStrongPassword()
  @MinLength(8)
  password!: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @ValidateIf((o) => o.password === o.retypedPassword)
  @IsStrongPassword()
  @MinLength(8)
  retypedPassword!: string;
}

